# Effect size of a mixed-effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, effect-size

**In short:** how to extract the different sum of squares from a mixed-effect model built using "lme" function in R (package nlme)?

**In long:** I am trying to finish my first experimental study. One reviewer asked me to report effect sizes for my mixed-effects model. I used mixed-effects models because I have a one-way repeated-measure design with one categorical predictor including different number of observations for each category (something the ANOVA does not like at all).

I found in [Bakeman (2005)](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03192707.pdf) and [Olejnik & Algina (2003)](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=fr&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Olejnik%20%26%20Algina%2C%202003&btnG=&oq=ol) that generalized eta squared is particularly suited, and should be easy to compute. For that I need the sum of squares of my model. Unfortunately, as said before, I am new to this kind of statistics. I am completely struggling to understand all the posts I find on the internet, and may have missed my answer somewhere. It may even exist a different estimate of effect sizes for my design.

Nevertheles, for the moment I go on the only way I found. Would anyone know how to extract sum of squares from the model built with "lme"?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried using the aov_4() function in the afex package? It should compute generalized eta squared (ges) values. See http://singmann.org/anova-in-r-afex-may-be-the-solution-you-are-looking-for/ for details.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement thank you for this suggestion! I did not know this package, which sounds really convenient for multiple uses. I will take a look at it.